# Postgres Distinct instead of Group By

Tags: postgresql

I am moving from mysql where I could just do a simple Group By to Postgres. I want to essentially group records by month and year, for example I would only get one record for January 2016, one for February 2016 etc.

I have the query working in Postgres but I am not sure if this is the most effective way, it just looks like there should be something better. I ended up having to run a Distinct on a combination of the year and month columns. year and month columns are integers.

```
SELECT distinct on (year::text || month::text) id, name, type, month, year 
FROM records 
WHERE type = 44 
ORDER BY year::text || month::text DESC, year, month  
LIMIT 12
```

Comment: Pg can also do "simple group by" queries.  Share your working original query from mysql.  Unless it's flagrantly violating the SQL standards, it shoud be very easy to translate to Pg's flavor of SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the concatenation:

```
select distinct on (year, month)
    id, name, type, month, year
from records
where type = 44
order by year desc, month desc
limit 12
```

Comment: Thank you, this is much cleaner